# Addition in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to increment a field, without first having to do a select query to retrieve its initial value ?

To be more specific : I have a field tracking the number of times a word has appeared. I know I can do this :
`SELECT count FROM table WHERE row = 1`, retrieve the value, add it to get the new value, and then `UPDATE table SET count = :newvalue WHERE row = 1`

... but I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in one query only (in the same way `$foo += 5` does in php)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it in the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table SET count = count + 1 WHERE row = 1
```

(Or `count = count + 5`, or whatever.)

Comment: I didnt know this was possible... Lol. Thanks !

Comment: Will do, waiting for the 15mn to pass.